# Подскажите метод авторизации вк через curl

Tags: php, вконтакте, curl

Может есть рабочий способ авторизации вк по curl на языке php, не используя протокол API Oauth ? Я слышал что на данный момент изменили способ авторизации и не пойму как правильно это релизовать...

Comment: А почему не через API?

Comment: И зачем писать свое, если можно пользоваться сторонней библиотекой? На одном githab'е таких уже [куча](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=vk+php&ref=searchresults&s=updated&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) Там же, кстати, можно посмотреть и способы авторизации

Comment: @ВОРОН все старое и нерабочее, хлам...

Answer (score 1):

`cUrl` в PHP - это только инструмент для отправки запросов каких угодно и куда угодно.
Для авторизации вам необходимо сделать ряд запросов на сервер ВК.

О том, какие именно - читайте [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites).
Естественно, для этого можно использовать cUrl.